# How to pass object in the header with post man post request?

Tags: java, post, http-headers, postman

I'm using postman and trying to pass an object in the header but getting an error for the converting from string to object... how would I do it right?

I'm attaching pictures from postman:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZp0W.jpg

this is the code on the server:

```
@RequestMapping(
      path= arrayOf(
              "/wristbands/upload",
              "/wristbands/upload/"),
      method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST),
      consumes = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
  open fun wristbandProcessNewAlgorithem(@RequestHeader(name = "X-V", required = true)  wristbandRecords: WristbandRecordNewInputDTO): ResponseEntity<*>{

   var res=wristbandProcessingService.processWristbandNewAlgorithem(wristbandRecords)
  return ResponseEntity(res,HttpStatus.OK)

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I think I found solution and it was moving the object from the header to the body and changing the code to be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(
      path= arrayOf(
              "/wristbands/upload",
              "/wristbands/upload/"),
      method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST),
      headers = arrayOf("X-V"),
      consumes = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
 open fun wristbandProcessNewAlgorithem(@RequestBody  wristbandRecords: WristbandRecordNewInputDTO): ResponseEntity<*>{

var res=wristbandProcessingService.processWristbandNewAlgorithem(wristbandRecords)
return ResponseEntity(res,HttpStatus.OK)

}
```